# Can't publish post using ajax

Tags: ajax, wp-insert-post

I have an issue,  i create three input in frontend(title,  body,  and name)

I process the value using wp-ajax,  and in my ajax function I use wp_insert_post  to create a new post.

if I put 'post_status =>' publish' in my wp_insert_post,  I get error 500 in ajax-admin, but if I remove it my code is fine.

I want create a post with publish status.  I also already put wp_publish_post after wp_insert_post in same ajax-function.  but also getting 500 error.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question, otherwise it’s impossible to know what the issue is. Based on your description though my guess is that you’re missing a comma after the line you’re adding.

Comment: 'post_status =>' publish'  should be  'post_status' => 'publish'

Comment: I also experienced the same, not sure how it came up like this, it just suddenly happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who are experiencing the same issue, there are few steps to take to determine the culprit.

1. Create posts manually in the WP Dashboard area (set it to future)
2. .. and manually publish (look for the error in the log).
3. step 1 and trash the post, in the Trash, try reverting that post (this generally create a log, and a log is all we need in this case).
4. Check for any plugin which filters the post publish.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot WordPress errors, you require to enable WordPress Debug, which can be done using **wp-config.php**.
You need to copy and paste the code in **wp-config.php** file shown below.
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: In an ajax request this won't give any help.